# Symfony Flex: What does symfony.lock file do?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-flex

After installing `symfony/serializer` I recognized that my `symfony.lock` file got changed:

```
diff --git a/symfony.lock b/symfony.lock
index ba6e23f..bfc391e 100644
--- a/symfony.lock
+++ b/symfony.lock
@@ -301,5 +301,8 @@
     },
     "symfony/asset": {
         "version": "v3.3.10"
+    },
+    "symfony/serializer": {
+        "version": "v3.3.13"
     }
 }
```

From what I understand, it was introduced with Symfony Flex, but how does it differ from `composer.lock` and why is it needed on top of that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is the proper lock file for [Symfony recipes](https://github.com/symfony/recipes) instead of trying to guess via the state of `composer.lock`

> Flex keeps tracks of the recipes it installed in the `symfony.lock` file, which must be committed to your code repository (CVS).
>   https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/flex#how-does-flex-work

It was introduced since Flex `1.0.34` version, originally to solve bugs like this: ["Configuring recipes executed twice"](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/192).

Comment: thanks for this **clear** answer. does it mean that `symfony.lock` could be removed from `vcs` ?

Comment: @waghanza I just updated the answer to be more explicit about this, the `symfony.lock` file must be committed into your CVS repository. Thanks!

Comment: No, the composer.lock is used for keeping track of the resolution of dependencies in the composer.json.  The Symfony recipes are something separate and not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @gview the question/answer is not about composer.lock, but symfony.lock file when Symfony Flex is used.

Comment: @yceruto: my comment was an answer to the question from waghanza.